# AutoCompleteExtender Control in ajax control toolkit

Tags: html, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a web service in .net which will retrieve the city name based on the given input text. The web service is working properly. I have used that web service in an AutoCompleteExtender Control in ajax control toolkit. But i am not getting the list of suggestions if i type anything in the textbox.

The web service structure is:
public string GetCompletionList(string prefixText)

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<!--.........................................
.........................................
.........................................-->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearchcity" runat="server" class="autosuggest"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" 
        ID="autoComplete1" 
        TargetControlID="txtsearchcity" 
        ServicePath="http://localhost:3935/SearchCity/searchcity.asmx" 
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
        CompletionInterval="1000" 
        EnableCaching="true" 
        CompletionSetCount="20">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
<!--.........................................
.........................................
.........................................-->
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

What should be the exact ServicePath and ServiceMethod? 
Whether the css file is necessary to get the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the official documentation, [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx). It denotes that the signature of the service method MUST match the following:

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
```

So, I would start by adding a method with this signature to your existing web service.

Also, I would suggest that you leverage some of the browser-based tooling (script debugging, http debugging, etc.) to ensure:

1. no javascript errors are occurring on you web page
2. your ajax request is successfully reaching the server
3. a proper response is being returned from the service

If you're not quite sure where to start, take a look at Chrome's Developer Tools, particularly, the [Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network).

As far as your current configuration is concerned (ServicePath, ServiceMethod, etc.), everything looks in place to me.